# javascript modifying app state array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and am writing my first app. I have an app state and am having issues with a mod function. I want one function to be able to change the value of any key found in my array of objects based on the 'drvName' key's value and other parameters to be entered into the function. However, I am encountering an inexplicable, to me at least, error in the console. The function will console.log('working') but right afterwards will return an error stating 'type error cannot read property drvName of undefined'. This is even after I have updated the state with an object. Any idea what I can do to fix this bug? Thanks ahead of time and forgive this post if its topic has been mentioned previously--I found nothing resembling it.

```js
const appState = []


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////MOD FUNCTIONs////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////CREATE DRIVER///////////////////////////////////
function createDriver(state, name, phone, scac, trkNum, trlNum, pic) {

  return state.push({
    drvName: name,
    phone: phone,
    SCAC: scac,
    trkNum: trkNum,
    trlNum: trlNum,
    picture: pic
  })

}
/////////////////////////CHANGE DRIVER INFO/////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////THIS DOES NOT WORK////////////////////////////////
function chgInfo(state, name, modKey, newVal) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= state.length; i++) {
    console.log('working');
    if (state[i].drvName == name) {
      state[i].modKey = newVal;
    }
  }
}
```

code here`

Comment: Additionally to "working" do `console.log(state)` (right before the loop)

Comment: We may need to see the code that is calling `createDriver` and `chgInfo`. It appears that you are not calling `createDriver` first, or it's doing something it shouldn't be doing with the return (which would be the new length of the array).

Comment: it logged the array with the object I created. still throwing the error though...

Comment: "it logged the array with the object I created. still throwing the error though" --- any chance you show it?

Comment: @AndrewR I called it from the console to test its functionality

Comment: "I called it from the console" --- how are we supposed to know that?

Comment: @zerkms my apologies, show what?

Comment: Enough details to help you, I suppose. At the moment you have shown 2 functions. So, they are syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<=` is causing the code to try to access state[1] even if you only called `createDriver` once, which is causing your current error.

Another issue I found is how you are using `modKey`. I assume that you are trying to update the property that is named in modKey, not actually set a modKey property. In the updated code below, it's accessing the property name stored in `modKey` to update the value instead of adding a `modKey` property.

```js
const appState = []


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////MOD FUNCTIONs////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////CREATE DRIVER///////////////////////////////////
function createDriver(state, name, phone, scac, trkNum, trlNum, pic) {

  return state.push({
    drvName: name,
    phone: phone,
    SCAC: scac,
    trkNum: trkNum,
    trlNum: trlNum,
    picture: pic
  })

}
/////////////////////////CHANGE DRIVER INFO/////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////THIS DOES NOT WORK////////////////////////////////
function chgInfo(state, name, modKey, newVal) {
  for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    console.log("working");
    if (state[i].drvName == name) {
      state[i][modKey] = newVal;
    }
  }
}

createDriver(appState, "name", "phone", "scac", "trkNum", "trlNum", "pic");
chgInfo(appState, "name", "phone", "new phone");

document.write(JSON.stringify(appState));
```

Comment: AndrewR thank you--big help! for some reason it won't let me tag you in the comment but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in this code:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= state.length; i++) {
```

Your condition should be `i < state.length`, not `<=`. The console will complain that state[i] is undefined because you're currently looping through `state.length + 1` elements, and the last element you're *trying* to access does not exist - hence the undefined error.

EDIT:

For the modkey issue, you need to use `state[i][modKey]` to access the property you want. The reason for this is that `modKey` is a string variable, and when you need to access an object's property based on a string/string variable, you need to use the `[]` operator.

For example:

```
var a = {"property1": 1};
var b = "property1"
console.log(a.b) // will throw up undefined
console.log(a[b]) // will log 1;
```

If you're using the `.` operator, javascript will try to access the property of a named "b", which does not exist. However, if you use `[]`, javascript will evaluate the value of b and return that value.
So you should have:

```
  if (state[i].drvName == name) {
      state[i][modKey] = newVal;
}
```

Comment: That did get rid of the error! thanks however now a new issue is seen when I pass in 'trkNum'  as the 'modKey' parameter --coming back as undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer for your other issue.